# Alert if available RAM is too low

Tags: windows-7, memory-management, resource-management

I am looking for a Windows 7 program that can give me an alert (e.g. pop up around the icon tray) whenever the ratio *available RAM / total RAM* goes below some configurable threshold. Gratis is better.

Comment: Do you turn off virtual memory (or severely limit it)?  Otherwise, won't Windows 7 always page memory when it gets low?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard yes virtual memory is turned off to avoid swapping

Comment: Okay, now it makes sense!  ;)

Comment: On Linux 100% of the memory being used is normal, it is actually a good thing. Isn't it the same on Windows?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul it's the same. (free vs available physical memory)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using similar tool in a form of lightweight plugin for IM client (client used as kind of container), but it takes only few lines of code, so here is "standalone" version: [memwarning](http://tomeko.net/soft.php#memwarning). It has no configuration, by default it warns when total memory usage is > 90% checking usage every two minutes. It doesn't show any window, just runs in background. If memory usage is exceeded it beeps with PC speaker three times and checks again after 1 minute. Use Code::Blocks/MinGW to change configuration (modifying ThreadProc()) and/or rebuild.

One disadvantage of using GlobalMemoryStatusEx() function is that it treats system cache memory as used which may give warning earlier than expected. I have no idea how to check memory usage without system buffers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script of Powershell I just wrote. To use it open up "Powershell" (It's in the start menu, already installed) and run it:

```
while ($true) {
    $available = (get-counter -counter "\Memory\Available Bytes").CounterSamples[0].CookedValue
    $thresholdInBytes = 100 * 1024*1024;

    echo $available

    if($available -lt $thresholdInBytes) {
        $wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell

        $wshell.Popup("Low RAM available",0,"Ok",0x1)   
    }
    start-sleep -s 5
}
```

Changed the threshold value if you want a value other than 100MB of ram. I'm licensing it with the WTFPL.